# Which file does OneDrive keep?

Tags: windows-10, sync, onedrive

I've searched on this particular issue many times and I can never find a clear description of how OneDrive manages files.

#### My issue is straight-forward:

I have two PC's both of with run Windows 10 and rely on the same Microsoft account for OneDrive storage (this is a personal account).

I often need to work on the same documents on both machines.  Usually OneDrive kicks in and syncs things before I shutdown the PC; however, sometimes the OneDrive sync engine hangs and I need to restart it.  Without knowing I shutdown anyways and attempt to continue where I left off on the other PC.  Because the syncing failed, the most recent files are not available on the other machine and I need to re-sync.  This process involves me booting up my laptop again and restarting the sync engine process, this seems to resolve the issue, but I have some concerns...

---

At some point during this problem, both PC's have different versions of the document on the local file storage.

- How does OneDrive choose which version to sync?
- Is it possible that one PC syncs files, then the other PC overwrites the more recent versions from it syncing to the old files?
- How can I be sure that I'm not losing work?

Comment: I use OneDrive in same way. I always get last version- which is that i change last. So if i change in PC1 some document, he is updated on PC2. Maybe in your case is something connected with internet issues or... i dont know.

Comment: It has been my experience that this is the same behavior I observe.  Taking the scenario that if I edit on PC1 and it doesn't sync, then edit on PC2 without realizing and it does sync.  I'm concerned that this could lose my changes that never synced on PC1 when it syncs next.

Ultimately, I'd like to get an understanding on how OneDrive operates really though...

Comment: Well. I didnt have that kind of issue. Can u check does PC1 is set to automatic syncing?  (check right click in tray on onedrive)... If not, try to disconnect and connect again. Maybe is some software error... but i try this today- no issues with my PC1, PC2, even with my phone.